# How to get href value?

Tags: javascript, href

To make it simple, I'm currently using javascript. How can I get the href value and stored it in javascript variable. I need extract all the attributes href values for each curriculum section and also each item in each section.

```
<ul class="curriculum-items-list">
 <li class="curriculum-section-container ng-scope">
  <ul>
   <li class="curriculum-item-container ng-scope">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec1_1.mp4">
   </li>
   <li class="curriculum-item-container ng-scope">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec1_2.mp4">
   </li>       
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="curriculum-section-container ng-scope">
  <ul>
   <li class="curriculum-item-container ng-scope">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec2_1.mp4">
   </li>
   <li class="curriculum-item-container ng-scope">
    <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec2_2.mp4">
   </li>       
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**Desire result**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec1_1.mp4
http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec1_2.mp4
http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec2_1.mp4
http://www.mywebsite.com/videoSec2_2.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get references to the `a` elements and then `Array.prototype.map` to extract the relevant data into an array:

```
var hrefs = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".curriculum-item-container a"), function (elem) {
    return elem.href; 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Vg8h/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var hrefs = [];
$(".curriculum-item-container a").each(function (i, a) {
    hrefs.push(a.getAttribute("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `querySelectorAll` to get all hrefs.

```js
let hrefs = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.curriculum-item-container a').forEach(a => {
  hrefs.push(a.href);
})
```